# npm error notarget for the Angular 6.0.2

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

Based on this [release schedule of Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md), Angular 6.0.2 is released as a stable version now, however when I try to install this version using npm, I get error notarget (shown below).

Also in npm webpage, the latest version that I have found is 5.2.10

Am I missing something here?

```
 notarget No matching version found for @angular/cdk@^6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps someone else: turns out that the stable version of Angular 6 is not yet released as shown in this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23540)

The released [schedule](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md) is approximate

Currently the latest stable version of angular/core is 5.2.10 as per [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core)

Comment: It's out now :)